# c# Assembly.LoadFrom with dynamic AssemblyResolve

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection, .net-assembly, assemblyresolve

I'm kind of stuck with dynamically loading plugins:

Theory: (Plugin) Dlls in a specific folder:

```
foreach(string path in Directory.GetFiles(...))
{
    Assembly myPlugin = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    foreach(Type type in myPlugin.GetTypes().Where(t => typeof(myPluginBaseClass).isAssignableFrom(t)))
    {
        Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

So far so good. 
Now there are issues with additional references in those assemblies, which can be solved by `catch(ReflectionTypeLoadException)` (to removed all null Types) and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ...` (to manually look for those missing dlls)

Now here is the issue: The referenced missing assemblies are specific for each implemented Plugin, so I need a individual search behavior implemented in each Plugin. My ideas / solutions so far:

- Having a global list of all possible DLL directories in my main application -> stupid because this won't allow to add further plugins without changing the main application code
- Having a (non static) dictionary of specific dll paths in each plugin -> can be forced by the `myPluginBaseClass` using virtual/abstract; But can't be accessed before creation of the instance (where those `AssemblyResolveEvents` are fired), so not helpful
- Having a (static) dictionary of specific dll paths in each plugin -> can be read before instantiation by using Reflection, but I can't add this to my `myPluginBaseClass` as a defined template, so errors possible
- Creating a individual Domain for each plugin and let them handle their own `AssemblyResolveEvent` -> But how?

I hope you can help!

Thanks in advance!
Robin

Answer (score 2):

Create domain seems to be adequat solution for plugin pattern.

You don't really need to define AssemblyResolve, you can simply configure the directory where AppDomain can find dependencies.

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.appdomainsetup.applicationbase(v=vs.110).aspx](http://AppDomainSetup)

Comment: Thank you for your response! It seems creating a new AppDomain seems to be a good approach. Although the problem remains that I only know at runtime where my missing assemblies are located (because I need to exchange those information from the registry and/or check multiple possibilities).
And as a result, each plugin can have multiple directories: the base dir of the Main.exe (AppDommain.CurrentDomain) + Subdir1 + Subdir2 + those additional dynamic locations...